# even function definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I saw many proofs for the fact $$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x) \, \mathrm dx =2\int_{0}^{a}f(x) \, \mathrm dx$$
 for even real function $f$, for example [see this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definite_Integral_of_Even_Function).
All proofs, which I saw, use the method of integration by Substitution, and this means that $f$ should be continuous.

Is there a simple proof for this fact without assuming that $f$ is continuous (based on the definition of the definite integral, or using upper and lower sums)?

Thanks.

Comment: Continuity of $f$ plays no rule here. It is totally irrelevant. No step used an assumption that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Also, substitution does not require the continuity of $f.$

Comment: What type of integration are we doing here, that you're interested in non-continuous functions?

Comment: integration by Substitution required that $f$ is continuous. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integration_by_Substitution

Comment: According to that article it is $\phi$ that needs a derivative and in the proof of the statement in the question, $\phi(x)=-x$.

Comment: @robjohn I saw this in the article "Let f be a real function which is continuous on I.
"
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integration_by_Substitution

Thanks

Comment: I believe that $f$ can be assumed bounded and get the same result. It is stated as such because the proof they use is simpler when $f$ is assumed continuous. If not, piecewise continuous is definitely sufficient.

Comment: @robjohn many thanks for your reply. I hope that you can explain this with more details?

Comment: @JohnJohn: for the piecewise continuous functions, just prove the substitution is valid on each interval where the function is continuous. To try extending from there, it depends on which integral is being used. There will be different proofs when using the Riemann integral than when using the Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we're on $[-1,1].$ Then

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[f(\frac{k}{n})+ f(-\frac{k}{n})] = 2\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n}).$$

On the left side we have Riemann sums converging to $\int_{-1}^1 f,$ on the right we have two times Riemann sums converging to $\int_0^1f.$ Thus $\int_{-1}^1 f= 2\int_0^1f.$